# Android layout, dragging or sliding?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

Now, I know this is going to sound just outright dumb.  But, what is it called when you have a smartphone or tablet and you drag your finger across the screen to move an application down for the purpose of accessing more elements that were not accessible on the screen?

The reason I am asking is because I dl'd eclipse and started learning android java the other day.  It's been great, a lot of fun.  But, I've actually managed to put a nice little application together.  The problem is, when I test it in some emulators; the screens are too small for the application and I cannot access to last few inputs and submit button.  I don't know what this stuff is called or what I can even google for to try to figure out how to get the screen to move down to access them.

Please, I'm being serious.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean ScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). It enables scrolling behavior like a website, allowing layouts to be "larger" than the physical screen size.

One thing to note; A `ScrollView` can only contain one direct child. So if your layout contains several `Views`, like `TextViews` and `Buttons`, you have to wrap them all in a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Layout with lots of childs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    

    <LinearLayout id="@+id/wrapper_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">     

        <TextView />

        <EditText />

        <Button />
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView
```

When you only got one child, you do not need a "wrapper" layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView id="@+id/lots_of_text_that_need_scrolling" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.  This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.  You're great!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your layout in a ScrollView. Then the screen will be able to scroll when you slide you finger up to display the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the word you're looking for is swiping.